# data not getting populated to the view from controller after routing in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am seeing no data in my view (Html) . where as i am getting data into controller from service as well.
Please let me know what i am missing .

Any suggestions what i am missing

Controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app') .controller('UserController', UserController);
    UserController.$inject = ['$scope', 'UserService', '$http', '$filter', '$rootScope','$location','$window'];
    function UserController($scope, UserService, $http, $filter, $rootScope,$location,$window) {


        $scope.editUser = function(userDetails){
            UserService.editUser(userDetails).then(editUserSuccess,editUserFailure);
            $location.path('edit');
        }


        var editUserFailure =function (error){
        };

        var editUserSuccess = function (response) {
             var userRow = response.data;
                $scope.edituserData=userRow;            
        };
    };  
})();
```

This is my service part

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').factory('UserService', UserService);

    UserService.$inject = ['$http', '$rootScope'];
    function UserService($http, $rootScope) {
        var service = {};
        service.editUser = editUser;
        return service;
        function editUser(editUserObj){
            console.log(editUserObj.userId);
            return $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: 'editUser',
              data: btoa(editUserObj.userId),
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

My routing from application

```
appname.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when("/edit", {
        templateUrl:"my.html",
        controller : 'UserController'
    });

});


my.html:
--------

When i am trying to get data in my html template 

 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                      <p class="text-right"><strong>Middle Name :</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                      <p class="text-left-user"> {{editUserData.screenName}}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add your template html? Also, you can use resolve in router provider and inject it to the controller.

Comment: You're missing .then(resolve, reject) to handle the data.

Comment: What does `console.log(userRow)` show if you put it before `$scope.edituserData=userRow`?

Comment: the code looks fine, did you try debugging to see if the http call return data inside editUserSuccess function?

Comment: What I  am doing is i am calling editUser controller method from another html where the html is getting rendered before the data is getting is populating to the view i guess. Any suggestions on it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your service just needs to return the data on success. Right now it is only returning the Promise.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').factory('UserService', UserService);

    UserService.$inject = ['$http', '$rootScope'];
    function UserService($http, $rootScope) {
        var service = {};
        service.editUser = editUser;
        return service;
        function editUser(editUserObj){
            console.log(editUserObj.userId);
            return $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: 'editUser',
              data: btoa(editUserObj.userId),
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            }).success(function(response){
                return response;
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Then in your `.then` success function in the controller, you should have the response available.

Comment: I was getting response back to controller .  after setting the data to the scope and going back to the view i am seeing empty only .   I tried to set a simple String in my callback function like $scope.edituserData="test"; even this is not working

Comment: What are you getting back as the response from your `editUserSuccess` function?

Comment: I am getting json object

Comment: Ok but what does the object contain? Does it contain the user data that you want? Is it empty? Please elaborate

Comment: I am getting the response what i am expecting into the call back  function once after call back is assigning data to view  its not reflecting it is still showing old data only .. dont know why ?

Comment: Then it must be something on the backend that is not updating the user. Can you post your backend code?

Comment: What i understood is that scope has been changed when the new template got loaded ,so the response is not setting to the view. Any suggestions ?

Comment: With the setup you have in your OP, that is not the case. In your routing file, the template is attached to the UserController so that will always be the scope it uses. Post your backend code so we can see what is being returned.